# excel - Find and Replace multiple text from cell values

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet with templated data. I want to be able to replace occurrences of words in `A1:A5` with what I type into `B1:B5` for the rest of the document.

Right now I'm going off of this (and I don't know much `VBA`):

```
Sub UpdatePartial()
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
.Replace "ZIPCODE", "B1", xlPart
.Replace "NAME", "B2", xlPart
.Replace "CITY", "B3", xlPart
.Replace "STATE", "B4", xlPart
.Replace "PHONE", "B5", xlPart
End With
End Sub
```

but I would like to replace the `A`s with the contents of `B1-B5` instead of the literal text *"B1","B2", ..., "B5"*, etc

Comment: This builds upon an earlier question, [Excel - Find and replace multiple words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13263154/excel-find-and-replace-multiple-words/13263284#13263284)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

`.Replace "ZIPCODE", "B1", xlPart`
use
`.Replace [a1].Value, [b1].Value, xlPart`

If you want to replace whole words only within a cell
(ie if you wanted to replace *cat* with *dog* but avoid changing *catscan* to *dogscan* then build in a space check before or after the string)

use
`.Replace " " & [a1].Value, " " & [b1].Value, xlPart`
`.Replace [a1].Value & " ", [b1].Value & " ", xlPart`

**Your updated question**

```
Sub UpdatePartial()
    Dim rng1 As Range
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set rng1 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Range(Cells(6, "a"), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count)))
    With rng1
        .Replace [a1].Value, [b1].Value, xlPart
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: you guys are awesome! thanks to you both. how would i make it not change the initial values of a1-a5?

Answer (score 1):

You would be able to reference to a cell (address) value with

```
Range("B1").value
```